# Get clusterrolebindings for an account?

Tags: kubernetes

How can I use kubectl to get all the roles that a service account has?

I can check the accounts bound to a particular role by doing

```
kubectl get clusterrolebindings somerole
```

Do I need to get all roles and then filter down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use this one. `system:authenticated` service account part of two roles

```
 kubectl get clusterrolebindings  -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.subjects[].name=="system:authenticated")].roleRef.name}'
system:basic-user system:discovery
```